# Android - How to secure API's from being hacked?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My app is having a few post API's. Unfortunately, there is no authorization required for that API.

How can I prevent API from being hacked by methods like HTTPCanary and decompiling of the app.

I have tried these things but still, people are able to get the API.

1. Base URL is encrypted and stored in gradle.properties file
2. User won't be able to use the app if HTTPCanary is installed (validation added in onResume of all activities) but not sure if the user uses any other apps like HTTPCanary.

Please help me with a failproof solution for this.

Comment: Is the API available on HTTP or HTTPS? HTTP will make the entire API path visible, so anyone can intercept it and invoke it. If HTTPS, you could try to hide the path in a native module. It's not encryption but it will only make it harder to read it. The real solution is configuring a DDOS protection on server-side

Answer (score 0):

use `https` for your server and being sure that you using "ssl pinning"
you can find more about it in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@krisnavneet/certificate-pinning-in-retrofit-android-using-certificatepinner-8506c5be117e)